# How to set fixed width and height for dynamic objects e.g. swf files

Tags: php, flash

I have these ready made swf files (read only) but with bigger size than my web page can nicely accommodate so I'm trying to set a fixed size e.g. 210x210 for all banner placements that will load on the site even if the files are originally of different sizes. The current code goes as follows:

```
<div id="adv">
<?php echo $userobj->addBanners(); ?>   
</div>
```

How to go about manipulating this code to set width and height?
Pls see this link to understand my problem, http://www.dev.homesinlagos.com/viewrpt.php
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

---------------------- UPDATE
Right, I see the issue on the site now. Your swf-object contains width and height info, which you need to change:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://active.macromedia.com/flash4/cabs/swflash.cab#version=4,0,0,0"
id="name">
<param name="movie" value="http://homesinlagos.com/banner/1288602972_Tip_fuse.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<embed name="name" src="http://homesinlagos.com/banner/1288602972_Tip_fuse.swf" SCALE="exactfit" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="210" height="210"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</embed>
</object>
```

---

you cann remove the style setting I told you to add in my first version of that answer

Comment: Thank you. I'm yet to try that though. The swf file has been put back up, visit my link again to understand the problem.